# OData Filter query designer not showing in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow

I have seen many people are referring to use ODATA filter query designer but in my Power Automate in Get Items, I don't see the filter query designer, it is the same as it was:
For example, I getting the same as below:

Article Reference: https://sharepains.com/2021/02/02/filter-by-content-type-power-automate/

[image]

In the same article, we could see he is referring to **ODATA query builder UI**:

[image]

The above **ODATA query builder UI**, I don't see in my Power Automate.

For this what I need to do to enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to turn on the experimental features in Power Automate for using ODATA query builder UI.

Check below article for more information; [How to Turn on Experimental Features in Power Automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/11/how-to-turn-on-experimental-features-in-power-automate/)

[image]

Comment: If we enable this, will it enable for all users in the tenant or only for the logged in user who enables it?

Comment: Only for the logged in user.